# Redux mapDispatch ToProps. What data should i pass as an argument?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

What should I pass as an argument in mapDispatchToProps (in the place where "????????" are)

my action is here:

```
function addTodo(text) {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_TODO',
        text: text

    }
}
export default addTodo
```

this is my component/container where I am using mapDispachToProps(){} and mapStateToProps(){}

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import addTodo from '../actions/index';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class TodoInput extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            inputValue: ''
        }
    }

     onChangeHandle(event) {
    this.setState({
      inputValue: event.target.value
    })
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {

    event.preventDefault()
    //this.props.dispatch(addTodo(this.state.inputValue))
    this.props.buttonClick(this.state.inputValue)
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>

            <input
            type = "text"
            value = {this.state.inputValue}
            onChange = {this.onChangeHandle.bind(this)}
            />
            <button onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return state
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    buttonClick: () => dispatch(addTodo(???????????))
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoInput);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to pass the inputValue with any name as a parameter "todoText" in this case.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    buttonClick: (todoText) => dispatch(addTodo(todoText))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use buttonClick like: `this.props.buttonClick(this.state.inputValue)`

Whan you write  `mapDispatchToProps`, you are defining a properties (**functions**) that use dispatch.

For your code `mapDispatchToProps` should be:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    buttonClick: (text) => dispatch(addTodo(text))
  }
}
```